# [SOLVED]how to send command to Gsm module from Arduino via serial port

Tags: arduino-uno, softwareserial, communication, gsm

Am using SIM7600X 4G HAT module (GSM) and Arduino Uno
after I start the module and Arduino, I receive data from Gsm module but I can't send any command to it.
On my Arduino board when I get data RX led flashing, and when I send command TX led flashing.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial myserial(3, 4); // gsm_TX, gsm_RX

void setup(){
  myserial.begin(9600); //Initialize GSM serial port
  Serial.begin(9600); //Initialize Arduino default serial port
}

void loop(){
  while(1){
    while (myserial.available()) {
      //Serial received data, output via mySerial.
      Serial.write(myserial.read());
    }
    while(Serial.available()) {
      //myserial received data, output it via Serial.
      myserial.write(Serial.read());
    }
  }
}
```

As the picture I send "AT" command or any command it no response.
it show only module start up command.
[image]

My circuit

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, On my circuit GSM module use an external source and my Arduino Uno use serial port source, So it cant communicate via pin because both ground of them did not connect to each other then the answer is connected GSM module GND to Arduino Uno GND.